# $ x^3<y^3 \iff x<y $ proof issue.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So I took a calculus course and my first homework has this one. I am stuck on this one for 2 days straight. Please help me; I will appreciate some hints.

So far we learned the axioms of a field and the axioms for inequality (trichotomy, transitivity, etc.)
Do I actually need to divide it into cases where both $x,y$ are with the same sign and another case where they are with different signs? 
Is there an elegant and short way for this?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669253/is-there-a-one-line-proof-of-xy-rightarrow-xnyn-for-n-an-odd-natural

Comment: you may use the fact that $f(x) = x^3$ is strictly increasing function.

Comment: Oh comon how comes I didnt find this actually the same question. Thank you sir !!!!!!

Comment: @user313448 How about $x\mapsto x^3$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: I didnt study any functions yet (I know them but not axiomatically...)

Comment: @echzhen: But that is exactly what we are asked to prove! user313448, I think you need to do more that "P therefore P."

Comment: @TonyK, Indeed my bad, I didn't notice that OP didn't learn anything about differentials.

Comment: For positive  integer $n$ and field  $ F,$ the characteristic $\chi (F)=n$ iff the sum of $ n$ "ones" is equal to zero. If $\chi (F)\ne n$ for any $ n\in N$ we say $\chi (F)=0.$ An ORDERED field is a field with a linear order $<$ such that $a<b\to a+c<b+c$, and $[a<b\land 0<c]\to a c<b c.$   Basic properties of an ordered field F include (1) $\chi (F)=0$... (2)  $1>0$... (3) $ x^2\geq 0.$.. (4)  $x>0\to 0>-x.$ This justifies some of the steps in Hagen von Eitzen's answer, which is a good A.

Answer (score 5):

$$x^3<y^3\iff y^3-x^3>0\iff (y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)>0$$
If we knew that $y^2+xy+x^2>0$ then we could continue with "$\iff y-x>0\iff x<y$".
Note that
$$ y^2+xy+x^2=\frac23(x+y)^2+\frac13(x-y)^2$$
is the sum of nonnegative numbers, so that $y^2+xy+x^2\ge 0$. But here we have equality only if both $(x+y)^2=0$ and $(x-y)^2=0$, which means $x=y=0$. But in that case $x^3<y^3$ and $x<y$ are alsoequivalent (namely, both are false).

Comment: Or notice $y^2+xy+x^2=\frac{1}{4}(2x+y)^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!!!!! This it the exact kind of proof I was looking for, as this one is very understood to me !!!!

Answer (score 4):

$$x^3<y^3\implies x^3-y^3<0\implies (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)<0$$

But the second factor is always positive since, as a quadratic in $\;x\;$ , its discriminant is

$$\Delta_x=y^2-4y^2=-3y^3\le 0$$

and equality only for $\;y=0\;$ (which is a trivial case), so it must be $\;x-y<0\;$

Comment: One could also write the quadratic factor as the sum $(x + \tfrac{1}[2} y)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} y \right)^2$, which is always nonnegative, and which is zero only when $x = y = 0$.

Comment: @Travis Thank you, but something came up wrong in your post.

Comment: The broken $\LaTeX$ (which is the result of a mistyped bracket) should read: $\left(x + \tfrac{1}{2} y\right)^2 + \left(\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} y\right)^2$.