# Show that for all $u,v \in \mathbb{R}, u>v$ if and only if $u^3 > v^3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that for all $u,v \in \mathbb{R}, u>v$ if and only if $u^3 > v^3$.

Hi, just wondering how everyone thinks best to prove this? I was thinking of using cases but not sure!

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$ x^3<y^3 \iff x<y $ proof issue.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672388/x3y3-iff-xy-proof-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use that $$a^3-b^3=(a-b) \left(a^2+a b+b^2\right)$$
It is $$a^2+b^2\geq 2|ab|$$ by AM.GM, so $$a^2+b^2+ab\geq 2|ab|+ab\geq 0$$ since $$2|ab|\geq -ab$$

Comment: Thank you, would it be wise to factories the quadratic further or am I missing something?

Comment: We have $$a^2+ab+b^2\geq 0$$ for all real $a,b$

Comment: I think you don't need cases, you need the factorization as i have written

Comment: How did you get the second line? I.E where is the 2 from

Comment: I have used the AM-GM inequality $$a+b\geq 2ab$$ for $$a,b\geq 0$$ and then i added $ab$ on both sides.

Comment: But how does this prove the claim that u>v?

Comment: If $$a>b$$ then we get $$a-b>0$$ and multiplying by $$a^2+ab+b^2>0$$ we get $$a^3-b^3>0$$

Comment: If $$a^3>b^3$$ then we have $$(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3-b^3>0$$ since it must be $$a>b$$